# Shiny/R - Make a single button send multiple responses

Tags: r, google-sheets, shiny, google-drive-api

I need the "send" button to send all app info to a spreadsheet saved in Google Drive (not just the first info); each for a column (Name, Age, Birth...). Thanks!

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

library(googlesheets4)
library(googledrive)

library(readr)
library(DT)


# Dashboard

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red",
                    
                    dashboardHeader(
                        title = "Controller"
                    ),
                    
                    dashboardSidebar(
                        
                        sidebarMenu(
                            
                            
                            menuItem(
                                
                                "Home",
                                tabName = "home",
                                icon = icon("home"))
                        )
                    ),
                    
                    dashboardBody(
                        
                        tabItems(
                            tabItem(
                                
                                tabName = "home", h2("Hello"),
                                
                                br(),
                                
                                box(
                                    h2(icon("id-card"), "Client"),
                                    
                                    width = 2000,
                                    
                                    br(),
                                    
                                    
                                    # Insery name
                                    textInputIcon(
                                        inputId = "name",
                                        label = "Name"),
                                    
                                    # Birth
                                    dateInput(
                                        inputId = "dob",
                                        label ="Birth",
                                        min = "1960-01-01",
                                        max = Sys.Date(), format = "yyyy/mm/dd", 
                                        language = "en"),
                                    
                                    textInputIcon(
                                        inputId = "age",
                                        label = "Age"),
                                    
                                    # Phone
                                    textInputIcon(
                                        inputId = "phone",
                                        label = "Phone"),
                                    
                                    # E-mail
                                    textInputIcon(
                                        inputId = "email", 
                                        label = "E-mail"),
                                    
                                    # Send
                                    actionButton("send", "Send"),
                                    
                                )
                                
                            )
                            
                            
                        )
                        
                    )
                    
)


# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    textname <- reactive({
        as.data.frame(input$name)
        
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$sendname, {
        Selfie <-   gs4_get('link')
        sheet_append(Selfie, data = textname())
    })
    
    observe({   dob <- input$dob
    if(!is.null(dob)) {
        days <- as.integer((Sys.Date() - as.Date(dob)))
        years <- as.integer(days / 365)
        months <- as.integer((days %% 365 ) / 30)
        age <- paste(years, 'year(s)', months, 'month(s)')                                          
        #print(age)
        updateTextInput(session, "age", value = age)
    }
    
    })
    
}  

# App

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can loop through `input` and gather everything in a df.

```
observeEvent(input$send, {
    require(tidyverse)
    
    #gather info of all the relevant inputs
    client_df <- c('name', 'dob', 'age', 'phone', 'email') %>% 
                   map_dfc(~ tibble("{.x}" := input[[.x]]))
    
    print(client_df) #this will print a df with one row in the console
    
    #Selfie <-   gs4_get('link')
    #sheet_append(Selfie, data = client_df)
})
```